# Cannot highlight last option in "select" element

Tags: html, google-chrome, cross-browser

Select element with four options, when I move the mouse over each of the first three options the option changes from black text on white background to white text on blue background, as expected. However, when I move the mouse over the last option its appearance does not change.

If I use a select with only three options, the last element is highlighted white on blue as expected.

---

### This is Google chrome issue

---

Comment: Which version of Chrome? I've got the Windows version here, and it doesn't behave as you describe. [Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a3Wtg/).

Comment: Chrome Version : 34.0.1784.0

Comment: 34.0.1796.2 here, so... does the problem occur with my fiddle?

Comment: @MrLister problem occurs for me on your fiddle, Windows 7, Chrome Version 32.0.1700.76 m

Comment: I'm having the same issue! Chrome Version 32.0.1700.76 m

Comment: @TusharGupta - this question was asked 3 days before that other question

Answer (score 4):

This issue is know and [blogged about on frankcode](http://frankcode.wordpress.com/2014/01/21/chrome-32-broke-the-internet/). The following workarounds exist:

- Change windows theme to Windows 7 Basic (may require a certain level
  of user permission)
- Use the scroll wheel or up and down arrows (fix for select box only)
- Upgrade to the Beta release / Canary (I would not recommend this)
- Move to another browser

Comment: Those solutions are all workarounds for myself as a Chrome user, but not general solutions for Chrome users visiting my websites. I'm guessing since this is a browser-level issue no HTML/CSS/JS solution exists short of circumventing the select tag entirely?

Comment: That is correct, short of rebuilding the select element (which is crazy talk) the user must wait for a fix. You could however identify the users OS and Browser version (from the agent string) and display a warning to user.

Comment: I don't want to recommend living on the edge, but so far I've found preciously few problems with the Canary. Never actual crashes or loss of data or whatever.

Comment: .. and of course, less than 1 day after I wrote that, Canary refuses even to start. Oh well.

Comment: Seems to be fixed in Version 32.0.1700.102 m

Comment: @joshuahedlund you are correct it is all working today, that was a [quiet release](http://frankcode.wordpress.com/2014/01/27/chrome-why-so-quiet/)

Answer (score 1):

It's a Chrome issue, fixed in chrome Version 32.0.1700.102 m. Update your Chrome to the latest version and the problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is happening since the chrome updated to the all changed version 32.. It persists in Version 32.0.1700.76 beta-m, other problems include scrolling issues.. if you install Chrome 31 the problem will likely go away.. would love a better solution but as of yet haven't found one..

Answer (score 0):

its a chrome default issue wait till new update availabe by chrome.